# Map NAS drive ip address to name

Tags: windows, network-shares, home-networking, nas, windows-home-server

I have a NAS drive on my local network at a static IP. i can browse this drive at \\10.0.0.x\

However, I would like to alias this ip to a more human readable name: \\server\

how do I accomplish this in Windows (10)?

Comment: What's the make and model of that NAS?

Comment: @DanielB WD MyCloud EX2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit HOSTS file and add name record for your NAS.

location:

> C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc

For example, if you wanted to use the HOSTS file to translate a host name of a computer called “printserver” into the IP address of 192.168.0.1, you would add this line:

> 192.168.0.1 printserver

You can add more than one host name to the same IP address. For example, if the computer called “printserver” also acts as a scanner called “scanserver”, you could use this line:

> 192.168.0.1 printserver scanserver

(Edit using elevated prompt / save to other location and overwrite ... )

info : https://www.petri.com/easily-edit-hosts-file-windows-10

Comment: Please include all relevant contents from other pages, in case they go down.

Comment: Sorry about that didn't know and i thought that once there is enough info already posted i did not have to elaborate. Will do form now on.